# MySQL Union Query not returning expected result,

Tags: mysql, union

MySQL query only returns the second SELECT results in the union and I have no idea why...can you plz help?

```
$query  = "SELECT name ";
$query .= "FROM nutrients ";
$query .= "WHERE name LIKE '%{$sqlsafe_query}%' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 30 ";
$query .= "UNION ALL ";
$query  = "SELECT name ";
$query .= "FROM supplements ";
$query .= "WHERE name LIKE '%{$sqlsafe_query}%' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 30";
```

Comment: typo in 6th line. No concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query  = "SELECT name ";
```

Are you lack of the . before the =?

Comment: That's the beginning of the query so "." is not needed I believe?

Comment: OMG yes I spotted one missing in the middle!

Comment: I've been coding 10 hours straight.. must be getting blind thanks sooooooooo much! muah